# Debug into vb.net framework

Tags: vb.net, debugging, frameworks

I have tried on more than one occasion to get source framework debugging to work in VS 2010/2012. I have tried again this week and give up. I downloaded the reference sources/symbols, setup the paths etc, it just does not work. A frustration vented in many other posts.

I have also installed ReSharper and DotPeek with the perhaps naive expectation that they would on the fly decompile the framework when I tried to step into it...but no, I just get a disassembly instead.

The best I have gotten so far is starting my VB app with F8 and being prompted to locate 'windowsformsapplicationbase.vb', which I can't find in the sources I downloaded, or a C# version.

I don't believe it is not possible to step into the framework source by either having the original source or using decompilation...so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you enable following option? "Options" (menu) > "Debugging" > "General" => "Enable source server support" (has to be checked)

Comment: Yes. Followed this article [link](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/serversetup.aspx) and this one [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc667410.aspx) and many others to no avail.